# What is the aim of this email? Is this a ping or sping or what?

Tags: domain, spam

I asked this on Webmasters, since it was related to me being webmaster, but it got closed as off-topic. Let's see if I get lucky here.

I received this spam in my catch-all. As a webmaster of the domain it was sent to, I am really curious what the reason for this mail is. It was sent to a non-existent user "tania" on my domain - here I used mydomain.zzz - what does the sender want to achieve? Since many mail servers have stopped backscattering, not getting a bounce would not mean anything, would it?
Thanks for enlightening me :) And if it is off-topic here too, please tell me why instead of just closing it.

UPDATE: What's with you people? *Vote to close, not a question, not on topic*! **Come on!** It is a question. I was sent here from WebMaster since it was not deemed on topic there. I am concerned and want to know -in case someone had an idea or maybe even KNEW what the AIM is. I KNOW it is spam. As a webmaster of my own domains I get many thousands of spams a week but they are all understandable - hence when I get something like this I get REALLY curious (and at least one comment shows that I am not alone) and I turn to StackExchange and get treated like an noob. Great.

```
Delivered-To: arbitraryname@mydomain.zzz
Received: (qmail 8015 invoked from network); 27 Jan 2011 02:32:47 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO p3pismtp01-021.prod.phx3.secureserver.net) ([10.6.12.26])
          (envelope-sender <Planet1@dt3ls.com>)
          by smtp35.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net (qmail-1.03) with SMTP
          for <arbitraryname@mydomain.zzz>; 27 Jan 2011 02:32:47 -0000
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: At4FAAlnQE1GVjtCVGdsb2JhbACWXo4gCwEWCA0YJLwyhU8EhRc
Received: from mx.dt3ls.com ([70.86.59.66])
  by p3pismtp01-021.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with ESMTP; 26 Jan 2011 19:32:47 -0700
Received: from 70.86.59.66
        by mx.dt3ls.com (Merak 8.9.1) with ASMTP id JXF39710
        for <arbitraryname@mydomain.zzz>; Wed, 26 Jan 2011 17:31:10 -0500
Return-Path: Planet1@dt3ls.com
Status: 
Message-ID: <20110126173109.4d9d6c3f2b@1c3c>
From: "Tech Support" <Planet1@dt3ls.com>
To: <arbitraryname@mydomain.zzz>
Subject: Information, as instructed.
Date: Wed, 26 Jan 2011 17:31:09 -0500
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: General-Mailer v.3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
  charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Quote:

I give it to you not that you may remember time, but that you might 
forget it now and then for a moment and not spend all your breath trying 
to conquer it. Because no battle is ever won he said. They are not even 
fought. The field reveals to a man his own folly and despair, and victory 
is an illusion of philosophers and fools.

William Faulkner
The Sound and the Fury
```

Comment: Combine 'shrooms, meth and other drugs with spam botnets you can rent. Not everything in this spam world is sensible (if anything). Nowadays lots of spam is just .. spam. No deeper motive involved.

Comment: Voted to close because it's neither a question with a possible answer, as we aren't spammers here ;) and it's also off-topic because it's not related to sysadmin stuff. Nevertheless: My guess is that this kind of spam is just some kind of testing, either for list quality or distribution method, since you have to test those botnets somehow if you want so sell them.

Comment: I voted as not on topic, but it also deserves the not a question. Its not really related to System administration.

Comment: This is very odd, I have received an email from Planet1@dt3ls.com and as I did not know where it came from I googled it and found this thread, the only google offering.

It also came to my "catch all" address, the really curious thing is that is contained a professional chef's recipe for BBQ sauce, something I have been searching for during the past week.

I am not tempted to thank them as it may be just phishing for valid addresses, however I will express my thanks ot them via this thread as the recipe actually looks good.

Bemused in West London

Comment: I am curious too. As with user68632, I googled and this was the first on the list. And the question is actually useful, if you consider that you need to understand your opponent.

Answer (score 9):

Dude, it's just spam, I get stuff like this all the time, just ignore it - it's good that you care but it's just odd unintelligible spam and/or fishing-bait.

Comment: There was no image with viagra and no "reply to get 500,000$" so completely pointless - unless there is something more sinister. Hence the question :)

Comment: yeah, some of them are just random these days, I get one every few weeks that just says something like "Are you home?" addressed to a different email every time - very odd. Mysterious ways I guess.

Comment: +1 for "Dude, it's just spam". I know that some people get overly concerned about spam but honestly I wish people would just accept that spam happens and get on with their lives. "Hey, is this spam?", "Hey, this looks like spam". Yes, it's spam. Nothing to see here. Please move on. Thank you.

Comment: totally with you joeq - it's not like I do anything to stop physical spam email either - though I have got a hell of a lot of take-away menus out of it, and an unnatural interest in replacement double-glazed windows...